# How to sign KeyInfo properties XAdES4j?

Tags: java, xml-signature, xades4j

I am using the test code included in the [XAdES4j](https://github.com/luisgoncalves/xades4j) package, I am doing a basic enveloped signature that includes the <*ds:KeyInfo*> element, but the code uses the KeyingDataProvider Object that doesn't allow me to set an ID, so when I create the DataObjectReference I don't know which URI to set.

Java original code:

```
 Document doc = getTestDocument();
 Element elemToSign = doc.getDocumentElement();
 SignerEPES signer = (SignerEPES)new XadesEpesSigningProfile(keyingProviderMy, policyInfoProvider).newSigner();
 new Enveloped(signer).sign(elemToSign);
```

How my code looks like:

```
Document doc = getTestDocument();
Element elemToSign = doc.getDocumentElement();
SignerEPES signer = (SignerEPES) new XadesEpesSigningProfile(
            keyingProviderMy, policyInfoProvider).newSigner();
DataObjectDesc obj1 = new DataObjectReference(
            "http://uri.etsi.org/01903#SignedProperties");
DataObjectDesc obj2 = new DataObjectReference(
            "#KeyInfo");
SignedDataObjects dataObjs = new SignedDataObjects()
            .withSignedDataObject(obj1).withSignedDataObject(obj2);
signer.sign(dataObjs, elemToSign);
outputDocument(doc, "document.signed.epes.xml");
```

What should I do to sign the keyinfo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently there's no way to sign the whole `KeyInfo` element. You can, however, set xades4j to sign the `X509Certificate` element within `KeyInfo` that contains the signing certificate. This is configured using [`BasicSignatureOptionsProvider`](https://github.com/luisgoncalves/xades4j/wiki/OtherSigningOptions#keyinfo-content).

Comment: Also note that you don't need to manually add reference to the singed properties element. The whole purpose of the library is to abstract you from this stuff. Please refer to the project's wiki on GitHub for more info.